# Easy css floating div... Cannont find what is psuhing it down

Tags: css, html, css-float

why wont this div float in next to the rest of my content boxes?

I had it working fine before but something is now pushing it down below the first fold of the page.. I have been starring at this for too long, can someone provide me some an idea of where to look? I am not asking for someone to do it for me, just guidance.

page in question:
http://dev.theatticlight.com/deals/a-must-have-beautiful-ruched-scarves/

Comment: Which div is out of place? And where should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you need to wrap your #content_wrap_deal and #content divs in one parent div. As it stands now, the #content div is preventing the #sidebar from being in it's natural place up top.

Just so you're clear, it would look something like this:

```
<div id="main_wrap">
    <div id="content_wrap_deal">Content Here</div>
    <div id="content">More Content Here</div>
</div> 
<div id="sidebar">Sidebar here</div>
```

You'll need to play with the CSS a bit to make sure that #main_wrap works properly, but that should help you get the sidebar back where it belongs.

Comment: Genius! I am going duh now.. Thanks for helping me look at this from another angle. Cheers!